# Search object within object and get the key

Tags: javascript, object, search

I have an object router shown below. lets say I have another `var x = "/podcast"` and I want to find which key this variable x would reside. For example in this case I want to return the value "M2"

How can I search this object router and it's sub-objects to return the appropriate key?

Thanks!

```
var router = {
  M1: {
    url: "/",
    description: "",
    title: "",
    image: "",
  },
  M2: {
    url: "/podcast",
    description: "",
    title: "",
    image: "",
  },
  M3: {
    url: "/about",
    description: "",
    title: "",
    image: "",
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you accept redundant values with different keys or only the first found value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get Array of object keys then [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), here is a working snippet:

```js
const search = '/podcast';

const router = {
  M1: {
    url: "/",
    description: "",
    title: "",
    image: ""
  },
  M2: {
    url: "/podcast",
    description: "",
    title: "",
    image: ""
  },
  M3: {
    url: "/about",
    description: "",
    title: "",
    image: ""
  }
};

const foundElement = Object.keys(router).filter((el) => router[el].url === search);


console.log(foundElement[0]);
```

Comment: What is the el variable? Or how is that part functioning?

Comment: `filter()` method takes callback function to filter the array elements, `el` is the single element generated by `Object.keys()`. I linked the documentation for these functions if you want to go deeper to understand it.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

- To get your keys you use `Object.keys(object)`
- To search the `key` you can use `filter()` or `find()`.
- To apply the condition you define `callback` function inside `filter`or `find`.

In my case, I used `find` function :

```
const foundElement = (router, searchableValue) => {
  const founded = Object.keys(router).find(
    (value) => router[value].url === searchableValue
  );
  return founded === undefined ? "Key not found" : founded;
};

const searchableValue = "/podcast";
console.log(foundElement(router, searchableValue));
```